# Grails 2.0 trouble with persisting BigDecimal

Tags: grails, h2, bigdecimal

I am trying to persist a BigDecimal in a brand new grails 2.0 app, and it's not behaving at all how I am expecting.

I make a new app called `l2bigdec` and add this domain class:

```
package l2bigdec

class PlayMe {
  BigDecimal imStupidOrSomething
  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

Then I put this code in the bootstrap:

```
import l2bigdec.*
class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    def thisThingIHate =  new PlayMe(imStupidOrSomething:0.912345).save(failOnError:true)
    println thisThingIHate.imStupidOrSomething
    PlayMe.withSession{it.clear()}
    def getItBack = PlayMe.find{it}
    println getItBack.imStupidOrSomething
  }
  def destroy = {
  }
}
```

Which prints:

```
0.912345
0.91
```

Why is it not printing 0.912345 both times?  Do I not understand BigDecimal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scale constraint allows you to control this:

```
...
BigDecimal myNum

static constraints = {
   myNum(scale: 6)
}
...
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/scale.html

Comment: What if i actually want a BigDecimal and not a rounded float and it needs to preserve every digit I give it?  Is this no longer possible in 2.0?

Comment: Can I set a larger default scale so I don't have to hunt through my project updating every BigDecimal?

Comment: If you're targeting a particular RDBMS, some have arbitrary-precision types you can use (`NUMERIC` in PostgreSQL, for instance)  Otherwise, no easy way that I'm aware to preserve arbitrary digits. I'm also not aware of a single spot to set the default scale. If your BigDecimal property names are similar across classes, you could use `grails.gorm.default.constraints`, described here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html